# How to compare property of a first element with a second element in a List?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a single list with objects. Let's call it `ItemList`. Objects have properties such as `Name, Code, ParentCode` and so on. Some of these items have the same `ParentCode` and I need to compare the first element's `ParentCode` with the next one in some conditions. So I am using an if condition like this:

```
if (ItemList.First().ParentCode != ItemList.ElementAt(1).ParentCode)
```

However, sometimes this causes some issues because the `ItemList` can have single element inside it and it throws argument out of range or index out of range exception. To overcome this I changed the code to this:

```
if (ItemList.Count >= 2 && ItemList.First().ParentCode != ItemList.ElementAt(1).ParentCode)
```

Sometimes I need to run the same method when the ItemList have only one element or the first element does not have the equal ParentCode with the second element so I use this condition:

```
if (ItemList.Count == 1 || ItemList.Count >= 2 && ItemList.First().ParentCode != ItemList.ElementAt(1).ParentCode)
```

All of these seems counterintuitive thus I am open to suggestions on making to code more maintainable and readable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly looks counter-intuitive? Your last code example pretty much spells out what you want in straightforward C# syntax and in my opinion is therefore readable. (By reading this code, the intent - i.e., what is tested here - is relatively easy to understand.)

Comment: you can shorten the last revision to `if (ItemList.Count < 2 || ItemList[0].ParentCode != ItemList[1].ParentCode)`

Comment: `ItemList.Count < 2 || ItemList.ElementAt(0).ParentCode != ItemList.ElementAt(1).ParentCode`, if `ItemList.Count < 2` fails, no need to check the opposite after `||`

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu, not equivalent to what is desired. What if ItemList.Count is zero (i.e., ItemList being empty)?

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman, not equivalent to what is desired. What if ItemList.Count is zero (i.e., ItemList being empty)?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace i assumed OP would want to pass the check in that case, but it may not be you're right. they can put emptiness check before this if statement though and it'll still work in that case.

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman, take the code in the question (the last `if` example) as reference, as there is little ambiguity in the code itself. Any possible solutions should result in the same behavior and thus result in the same outcome under the same conditions.

Comment: @MySkullCavelsADarkPlace Response to your first comment, I felt like it is counter-intuitive because I am using two more conditions to skip index out of range error. After the answers I see that it is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

A couple other Linq functions may help here, depending on the use-case. I'm not sure I fully understand why you'd only want to compare the first 2 elements though. What if it has 10 or 100 items? Only the first 2 matter? If it can only ever have 2 elements because of some other business logic, then consider creating a class that holds exactly 2 items, and put the "comparison/validation" logic inside that class. A constructor that accepts 2 parameters, first + second instance, should ensure validity of the wrapper class.

Either way... for a purely LINQ solution...

1. `ItemList.GroupBy(x => x.ParentCode).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)` ... will get you a list of "groups" that contain more than 1 duplicate ParentCode. Iterating that will provide you with a "Key" representing the ParentCode or whatever you group by.
2. `ItemList.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` ... will get you the second element, if it exists, otherwise it will be the default for whatever type is in the list

Comment: I only want to compare the first two elements because index is removed after some other conditionals inside while loop, therefore ParentCode's of the items are constantly changing.

Comment: To provide a proper solution we'd need to know the overall design that winds up in this section of code. There may be a cleaner approach. Either way the .Skip LINQ function would clean up your code above quite a bit. No need to compare counts and whatnot, just check for null and/or equality on the array. The "?" operator at the end of "FirstOrDefault()" would allow null-safety checking comparison on 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you have to use linq here? I feel like just referencing the objects directly is just as good of a solution.

```
if(ItemList.Count == 2)
{
  if(ItemList[0].ParentCode != ItemList[1].ParentCode)
  {
    ..do stuff..
  }
}
```

Yes, the code isn't as flat, but this is extremely readable. If you need to compare the 0th value to more than just 1st value, checking that the list's length is greater than or equal to 2 and using a for loop will work just fine.

```
if(ItemList.Count >= 2)
{
  for (var i = 1; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
  {
    if(ItemList[0].ParentCode != ItemList[i].ParentCode)
    {
        ..do stuff..
    }
  } 
}
```

Only suggesting a non-linq solution because you didn't mention that it had to be linq. This code is still extremely readable and has no difference in performance. Also, as you mentioned in your post, none of this code seems counterintuitive.

Comment: In your second snippet you are comparing with `ItemList[i].ParentCode`, but `i` is the item itself and not its index.  I'd fix this by changing to `for (var i = 1; i < ItemList.Count; i++)`; you need to skip the first item, anyways, so you're not comparing `ItemList[0].ParentCode` against itself.